# "may you ask" or "might you ask"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> What is the explanation behind this answer, **might/may** you ask?

Is this sentence grammatically correct, if so which should I use and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammatically they're correct, but the word order is somewhat archaic or poetic sounding: "*you might/may ask*" would be better colloquially.

With the question spelled out, both options mean more or less the same.

> You might ask

**anticipates (and preempts) the question being asked**, and therefor requires a question being asked nearby (like in your case). It can be used rhetorically.

> You may ask

puts more emphasis on the **possibility or permission of asking a/that question**.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that "you might/may ask" is better!